# Delphi.Personality is not avaliable

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

Recently, I get this error, and all Delphi-related project/file creation items are missing:

> The project can not be loaded because the required personality Delphi.Personality is not available..

What I need to do is select "Manage Platform" and then RAD Studio will reinstall some components and restore the project menu.

However, the issue will occur again when I close and re-open RAD Studio.

I did not have such a problem before. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do an uninstall and then reinstall. Three's not much else you can do other than that, and if that doesn't work, contact EMBT support directly for help.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error, closing and opening delphi 11 for several times, the problem fixed. It looks like that's a temporary error.

Answer (score 6):

Got the same error. This worked for me:

In the IDE, open Tools - Manage platforms and hit Apply (without changing anything)

Close/open the IDE a then the project opens fine.

found this solution here https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/7007-rad-studio-104-community-edition-missing-delphipersonality/

Comment: Just got this issue on rad.11.3, opening menu Manage Platforms, a popup error show, closing and re-opening the IDE fixed it.... ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the .dproj file and opening the .dpr or .dpk, which recreates the .dproj, fixed it for me. HTH

Comment: Delphi 11 here. Unfortunately opening DPR just opened it in the IDE like a text file (albeit with code highlight. It didn't recognized it as a project file not recreated the DPROJ.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error previously when running RAD Studio 10.02. Uninstalling that and installing RAD Studio 10.04 did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same Error, but for me I combined most answers, and it works well on Delphi 11.2 so here is my steps:

1. Just open and close (as admin) several times.
2. Open the .dpk only!
3. Close it then open the project again and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error after installing Visual Studio.

For me it fixed itself when i open Delphi as admin, close, and open again.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if it relates to Visual Studio usage at same time as Delphi .. and debugging in both .. Closing Visual Studio and Delphi and reopening Delphi corrected message/issue for me.